# SQL combine two query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I can't use a Union because it's not the result I want, and I can't use join because I haven't any common column. I have tried many different SQL query structures and nothing works as I want.

I need help to achieve what I believe is a really simple SQL query. What I am doing now is

```
select a, b 
from (select top 4 a from element_type order by c) as Y, 
     (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (NULL), (1), (2), (3)) AS X(b)) as Z
```

The first is a part of a table and the second is a hand created select that gives results like this:

```
select a; --Give--> a,b,c,d   (1 column)
select b; --Give--> 1,2,3,4   (1 column)
```

I need a query based on the two first that give me (2 column) :

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
```

How can i do this? UNION, JOIN or anything else? Or maybe I can't.

All I can get for now is this:

```
a,1
a,2
a,3
a,4
b,1
b,2
...
```

Comment: Are the columns you are trying to select in different tables? Or are they both part of the same table?

Comment: Thx for the info ill try to remember i have update my comment. As i have say in the question sorry for the bad english.

Comment: It might be more useful for you to update your question with an obfuscated version of your table structure and the desired output that you are trying to get.

Comment: The question is updated a much better way (thx for SandPiper), the output i am trying to get is on it and i dont think the table struct is needed here. Because the data type here doesn't matter. But if you think you need it to help i can try to give you the complet structure of it

Comment: What he means is give some sample data for both of your fields and show how they are related. Part of the problem you are having so far is that you haven't clearly explained how the values in A and B relate to each other, so why should they logically end up in the desired end format?

Comment: It because they are not related. I make a DB migration and i need to add some data to existing raw so as i do in the exemple provide in the question, the second query create is own data and not from a table.

Comment: Also, in the future please tag your question with the database software you are using. Solutions can be vastly different between Oracle, MySQL, or MS Access.

Comment: I have think about it but it s not a matter related to the software so thats why i havent put it in the tag but you right i think i can put it in the question next time

Comment: No, sandpiper is right.. you really should put the DB you're using in the tags. I search for questions using sql, oracle and sqlserver. I don't search for questions using MySQL tag, but I end up seeing a healthy amount of them thanks to sql tag, but it's always a bit of a drag remembering what MySQL doesn't support compared to the big 2. This questions answers for example, none work on MySQL because it doesn't have. XXX() OVER() functions. By tagging with DB you're using you get experts from that DB, you imply which syntax to get your answers in. SQL beyond basic ANSI stuff is not a standard!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can user row_number() to achieve this,

```
select a,row_number() over(order by a) as b from element_type;
```

As you are not taking second part from other table, so you do not need to use join. But if you are doing this on different tables the you can use **row_number()** to create **key** for both the tables and bases on those keys, you can join.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thx for the answer it's exactly what i was looking for i didn't know the rank() function, ill take a look to see what it does exactly.

Comment: welcome, there are another function like rank(), dense_rank()... for other combinations.

Comment: I'm -1 this because you said "rank can be used to create key.." but keys are typically unique, and rank's output is not guaranteed to be unique for an given set of rows.. Other than that, the post is fine, but do not use RANK() to create keys with which you join this table data to other tables

Comment: *Unless you are using rank on an already existing set of unique values. However, that would end up just being a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join two tables together purely on the order the rows appear, then I hope your database support analytic (window) functions:

```
 SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x) as rown FROM table1 t) t1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x) as rown FROM table2 t) t2
  ON t1.rown = t2.rown
```

Essentially we invent something to join them on by numbering the rows. If one of your tables already contains incrementing integers from 1, you dont need to ROW_NUMBER() OVER() on that table, because it already has suitable data to join to; you just invent a fake column of incrementing nubmers in the other table and then join together

Actually, even if it doesn't support analytics, there are ugly ways of doing row numbering, such as joining the table back to itself using `id < id` and `COUNT(*) .. GROUP BY id` to number the rows. I hate doing it, but if your DB doesnt support ROW_NUMBER i'll post an example.. :/

Bear in mind, of course, that RDBMS have R in the name for a reason - related data is.. well.. related. They don't do so well when data is unrelated, so if your hope is to join the "chalks" table to the "cheese" table even though the two are completely unrelated, you're finding out now why it's hard work! :)

Comment: Even if Pirate's answer already work for what i want to do ill test your solution later, i am sure it will help me later on other query matter. Thx for the help.

Comment: Be careful with RANK(), as it doesn't count up if two rows have the same value.. i.e. a,b,b,c would rank as 1,2,2,4, and they would dense_rank as 1,2,2,3. ROW_NUMBER() will just number the rows 1,2,3,4

Comment: Also @MaxenceBovier-Lapierre, this appears to be an Oracle solution. If you are using another database you might not have those functions available. That is why it is important to tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using row_number. I've created something that might help you. See below:

```
declare @tableChar table(letter varchar)

insert into  @tableChar(letter)
select 'a';

insert into  @tableChar(letter)
select 'b';

insert into  @tableChar(letter)
select 'c';

insert into  @tableChar(letter)
select 'd';

select letter,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by letter )  from @tableChar
```